# Gradient of weak solutions of elliptic PDE at interfaces

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega$ be a $C^1$-domain partitioned into two open sets $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$ with interface $I=\partial\Omega_1 \cap \partial\Omega_2$.

Now, say $u \in H^1(\Omega)$ is a weak solution of a second order elliptic PDE with piecewise smooth (and bounded) coefficients in $C^\infty(\bar\Omega_1) \cap C^\infty(\bar\Omega_2)$  (that are discontinuous across $I$).

One has $u \in C^\infty(\Omega_1) \cap C^\infty(\Omega_2)$ due to interior regularity. Also, from De Giorgi-Nash-Moser theorem one gets that $u \in C^\alpha(\Omega)$ for some $\alpha >0$ (and thus continous across $I$).

Now, the gradient must be discontinous across $I$ (due to transmission conditions). In this setting, is possible to get any smoothness for the trace of $\nabla u$ from either side (for smooth enough $I$) or can it be arbitrarily bad? From $u \in H^1(\Omega)$, one only knows the trace is in $H^{-1/2}(I)$, so it does not even have to be a function.

The derivations of transmission conditions for weak solutions (for example [here](http://www.latp.univ-mrs.fr/~chaabi/ARTICLES%20IMPORTANTS/Autres%20articles%20interessant/Livres/Attouch%20Book.pdf), at page 240) I've seen so far seem to assume that $\nabla u|_{\partial\Omega_1}$ and $\nabla u|_{\partial\Omega_2}$ can be continuously extended to $I$ ad hoc.

Comment: Do you know if the $C^\alpha(\Omega)$ estimate is still valid if we additionally impose a jump condition for the normal derivatives accros the interface like $\epsilon\nabla u_1\cdot n-\epsilon\nabla u_2\cdot n=g$ on $I$, where $u_1,u_2$ is the restriction of the solution $u$ to each subdomain and $\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2>0$ are constants in $\Omega_1, \Omega_2$ respectively ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be arbitrarily bad, I don't see a possibility of a continuous extension unless the singular part is manually removed.

For example, let $\Omega$ be the unit disk in $\mathbb{R}^2$: $\{(x,y): x^2 + y^2 < 1/e\}$, and 
$$u = \ln \Big(\big|\ln (x^2+y^2)\big|\Big).$$
It is easy to check that $u\in H^1_0(\Omega)$ under the polar coordinate system. We have:
$$\nabla u = \left(\frac{2x}{(x^2+y^2)\ln (x^2+y^2)}, \frac{2y}{(x^2+y^2)\ln (x^2+y^2)}\right),$$
Let $\Omega_1$ be the upper disk and $\Omega_2$ be the lower one, so that $I = \{(x,y): x\in (-1/\sqrt{e},1/\sqrt{e}), y=0\}$. The tangential derivative of $u$ on $I$ is:
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial s}\Bigg|_I = \nabla u \cdot (1,0)\Big|_I = \frac{1}{x\ln x},\tag{1}
$$
This thing is not even $L^1$-integrable.

Now for the transmission condition, for above $u$, we can see that on $I$ the normal derivative is 0:
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}\Bigg|_I = \nabla u \cdot (0,1)\Big|_I = 0.
$$
Thus we can easily use this function as a building block to cook a function satisfying the transmission condition, yet still the tangential trace of $u$ on I is not something we can control or continuously extend. For example, letting 
$$
f = \begin{cases}
-\alpha_1\Delta \ln \Big(\big|\ln (x^2+\alpha_1 y^2)\big|\Big) &\text{ in } \Omega_1,
\\[2mm]
-\alpha_2\Delta \ln \Big(\big|\ln (x^2+\alpha_2 y^2)\big|\Big) &\text{ in } \Omega_2,
\end{cases}
$$
where $\alpha = \alpha_1$ in $\Omega_1$ and $\alpha=\alpha_2$ in $\Omega_2$ is a piecewisely defined constant. This $f$ can be proved to be in $H^{-1}(\Omega)$ because it is the Laplacian of a piecewisely defined $H^1(\Omega)$ function $u$, which is the weak solution to $-\operatorname{div}(\alpha \nabla u) = f$. The tangential trace of $u$ will be as bad as (1).

---

Lastly, I believe you meant to say the page 240 on that book, also notice the obtaining of the transmission condition is equation (6.77), this says that 
$$
\alpha\frac{\partial u}{\partial n} = \beta \frac{\partial u}{\partial n} \; \text{ on } I
\; \text{ in the distributional sense}, 
$$
for we have a smooth testing function with an integration on their product. This only tells us that they agree with each other on $I$ weakly, and tells us nothing about the trace regularity for $\nabla u$. $H^{-1/2}(I)$ is as good as you can get.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! If I understand it correctly, you mean that for this $u$, one can build coefficients such that $u$ satisfies the corresponding elliptic PDE in the upper and lower discs, so that it is a weak solution in $\Omega$ (since it also satisfies the transmission conditions)?

Comment: Unfortunately, I posed the question a bit badly (I edited it, I hope you don't mind). I forgot to add the requirement that the coefficients are bounded. As far as I know that is necessary to apply Di Georgi-Nash-Moser. I think this should rule out your counterexample (since it is unbounded at $0$, which should not be possible according to Di Georgi-Nash-Moser)?

Comment: @Wolf The example I gave was a classical example that $W^{1,2}$ cannot be embedded into continuous function space. Di Georgi-Nash-Moser does rule out the $\ln(\ln|p|)$ case (homogeneous right hand side data), however, I suggest you take a look at the construction by Kellogg (http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00036817408839086#.UoEixFRDtl4). Here the solution $u \in H^{1+\epsilon}(\Omega)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and is harmonic except a point, and can be embedded continuously into $C^{0,\alpha}(\Omega)$ for any $\alpha < \epsilon$. Still $\nabla u$'s trace is not $L^2$-integrable on $I$.

Comment: @Wolf Well, my answer is more like a discussion, too long to be a comment. I am waiting to see if someone can come up with a proof of such thing, under certain assumptions, of course.

Comment: Thanks again. I will have a look at the paper by Kellogg.